# How do I reference another field in mongoDB Schema instead of ObjectID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas:

```
const book = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String
  pages: Number
  description: String
  author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
}

const Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)

const Author = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
  age: Number
  countryBorn: String
}

const Author = mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema)
```

After calling API, I want to display a list of data from Book Schema. For example:

```
function Book(book){
  const {title}, {pages}, {descritpion}, {author} = book; 
  return (
    <h1> {title} <h1>
    <p>{pages} , {description}<p>
    <p>{author}<p> 
    );
  }
```

For the {author} part, it is currenlty displaying the ObjectID "61422843cf091092020" but instead, I want the name of the author to display, e.g. "Samuel". How do I display this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoose's [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to to this:

```
Book.
  findOne({ ... }).
  populate('author').
  exec(function (err, book) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // book.author will now be populated
  });
```

Then, in react you can access the name property on the `author` object:

```
function Book(book){
  const {title}, {pages}, {descritpion}, {author} = book; 
  return (
    <h1> {title} <h1>
    <p>{pages} , {description}<p>
    <p>{author.name}<p> 
    );
  }
```

Comment: which part do I write that? @eol

Comment: Currently I have
const books = async (req,res) => {
    try { 
        const book = await Book.find({'pages': '200'}).populate({'author', 'name' })
      
        return res.send(book); 
    } 
    catch (err) { 
        return res.send("Error") 
    } 
}

Comment: Why are you populating `name` as well and why are you using an object? Just use it exactly like I did: `await Book.find({'pages': '200'}).populate('author')`

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed out on a detail earlier on. I want to populate the name in Author schema. Is the way I did it wrong?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Once you've populated the author object as I did, you can access then `name` propert in react.